# Define a timespan of 6 months

Tags: c#

I have a property of a model in C# which is of type TimeSpan.

Can anyone help me with the following scenario:
How can I set the value of that property to be of an interval of 6 months?

While creating this object, I want to set this default value of 6 months to the TimeSpan property, that's my goal.

Comment: "6 months" isn't a `TimeSpan`. It is not a constant span of time. The number of second in "6 months" varies depending on which 6 months you are talking about.

Comment: `TimeSpan` doesn't do months, probably because it's an ambiguous number of days. You would need a custom field.

Comment: You may want/need to consider moving to Noda Time if you actually want/need to work with the actual complexities of such an ambiguous period. `Period` is the type there that deals with this sort of ugliness.

Comment: 6 months can be ambiguous, e.g. let it be 6 months starting from today - `30 August 2023`, what is the end of the interval? `29 Feb 2024` or `1 Mar 2024`? Waht about 6 month interval starting from `29 August 2023`, `31 August 2023`?

Answer (score 3):

As others already stated, the length of "6 months" is ambigous and depends on the start date. If you just want to get a date "in 6 months" in the common meaning  (ie jump from Aug 15th to Feb 15th) regardless of how many days the months inbetween have you could do as follows

```
var date1 = DateTime.Today; //or whatever date you want to start at
var date2 = date1.AddMonth(6);
```

This will follow the "common sense" logic to calculate the resulting date. Ie `date2` will (if possible) be on the same day of the respective month as `date1`. So if `date1` is 2023-08-15, `date2` will be 2024-02-15. If that's not possible, for instance if `date1` is 2023-08-31 but there is no 2024-02-31, you will receive the last day of the target month, ie 2024-02-29. You can calculate a timespan from these two dates via

```
var span = date2 - date1;
```

If you really need a `TimeSpan` but you don't have a reference date, you will need to define how many days your "6 months" will have. But be aware, that adding such a fixed span to an arbitrary date many times won't give the expected result ...

If you can change your model, I'd suggest to move away from using a `TimeSpan` but use a descriptive approach. For instance a string like `6M`. And when you have a reference date, you can calculate how long that will actually be.

Answer (score 0):

You do know that 6 months is not a defined timespan per definition as the length of 6 months vary depending on the start date? A timespan defines a specific span of times. It can not specify 6 months by definition of, you know, the calendar.